# Sending vectors over TCP-is it done using the ObjectOutput?

Tags: java, vector

Okay,I am working on a program to hold the names and paths of multiple files within vectors and sending these from the server to the client. So I have simply tried to send a single vector with the single entry for one file,but to no avail. The vector initialization in the Client code does seem a bit weird, is it incorrect to use the ObjectInput and ObjectOutput interfaces to send vectors? Or am I just doing it incorrectly?
Server code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
    class TCPServer
    {
   public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
      {
         String clientSentence;
         ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);
         Vector<String> name = new Vector<String>(3, 1);
         File f0=new File("C:/Downloads","hjd");
         name.addElement(f0.getName()); 


         while(true)
         {
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader inFromClient =
               new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
            if(clientSentence!="hjd")
            outToClient.writeBytes("Please enter correct directory/filename");
            else{
            OutputStream socketStream = connectionSocket.getOutputStream();//output stream where the object is to be written
            ObjectOutput objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socketStream);
            objectOutput.writeObject(name);//no error during compilation of this line however



    } 
  }
}
```

And the client code which gives me an incompatible types found error in the vector declaration line:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;


class TCPClient
{
 public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
 {
  String sentence;
  System.out.println("Enter name of file as hjd");//I will later expand this to add more options
  BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6789);
  DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
  sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
  outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
  InputStream socketStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
  ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(socketStream);
  Vector<String> name = objectInput.readObject();//This is the line I am recieving an error on,saying "incompatible types found"
  System.out.println("The name of file is:"+name.get(0));
  clientSocket.close();
 }
}
```

Summarizing, can I send a vector using these interfaces? If no, then how do I send a vector over TCP? If yes, what is the proper declaration of the erroneous line,since this one does not even have size or incr of the vector mentioned?

EDIT--
Now thanks to ALex, the error is gone. I have edited that declaration as so:

```
if(objectInput.readObject() instanceof String){ 
   String a=(String)objectInput.readObject(); 
   System.out.println("The name of file is:"+a); 
}else if(objectInput.readObject() instanceof Vector){
   Vector<String> name=(Vector<String>)objectInput.readObject(); 
   System.out.println("The name of file is:"+name.get(0)); }
```

But while running of the program an exception is generated saying my ObjectInputStream is corrupt. What am I missing?

Comment: Your code looks OK. Are you running different versions of Java on the client and server?

Comment: @Alex Nope,actually running them on the same system, so I don't think that's possible. And could you then please tell me how I declare the size and incr of the Vector name in the Client code?

Comment: If you're getting an exception, then you should edit the question to include the full stack trace.

Comment: @Alex Okay,here is exactly what I am receiving:
TCPClient.java:19:incompatible types found
:java.lang.Object required:java.util.Vector<java.lang.String>
Vector<String> name = objectInput.readObject();
                                      ^
1 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
Vector<String> name = objectInput.readObject();
```

The problem is that the [ObjectInputStream.readObject()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject%28%29) method is defined to return an `Object`, so you cannot assign its return value to a variable declared of type `Vector`. To make this work you need to explicitly cast the return value:

```
Vector<String> name = (Vector<String>)objectInput.readObject();
```

This will get you past the compile error, but you'll have further problems because the server code writes either a `String` or a `Vector`. So on the client side, you would have to check the type of the object that you read from the stream (using `instanceof`) before casting it to the appropriate type.

Comment: Thank you,that makes sense. However, how do I assign the default length and incr of this vector?

Comment: You can't. When using an ObjectInputStream, the deserialized object's internal fields are set based on the values read from the stream, so they will be the same as what was written on the server side. If you want to change those, you'll have to create a new Vector and copy the contents of the deserialized vector into it.

Comment: Okay, so now I have edited that line as so:
if(objectInput.readObject() instanceof String){
  String a=(String)objectInput.readObject();
  System.out.println("The name of file is:"+a);
  }
  else if(objectInput.readObject() instanceof Vector){
  Vector<String> name=(Vector<String>)objectInput.readObject();
  System.out.println("The name of file is:"+name.get(0));
  }
The error is gone! But while running of the program an exception is generated saying my ObjectInputStream is corrupt. If it's not too much trouble,can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Edited a cleaner version of the code in the original question.